# Output of Hex of ino

Tags: arduino-ide

I have a hex file of a sketch i.e. `sketchname.ino.hex`. Can I find out anything from that hex file ?  Can I see the output or anything ? Can I upload it on arduino ?

Comment: Not really...  I mean, if it was mission-critical there might be a way, but in general the effort to do so would be more than simply rewriting the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a hex file of a sketch i.e. sketchname.ino.hex. Can I find out anything from that hex file ?

That is a binary image of the compiled sketch in a hexadecimal notation. You *could* spend hours disassembling it if you understood the right tools to use.

> Can I see the output or anything ?

You can convert it back to a crude form of assembly language maybe, but that is all. Understanding what that means takes skill and knowledge.

> Can I upload it on arduino ?

Sure. It's a compiled program ready to be uploaded to an Arduino.

```
avrdude -D -patmega328p -PCOM3 -b115200 -C/path/to/avrdude.conf -c arduino -Uflash:w:sketchname.ino.hex:i
```

Comment: Thanks, I just few queries regarding uploading the code. I have Arduino Uno and Due so how do I change the command for them and will it harm the Arduino ? And how can I find what the code is doing after uploading it ?

Comment: Arduino and Due use completely different programs, and the entire systems are completely different. You can only upload the HEX to the chip it was compiled for.

Comment: How will I verify for which system is it for. I have few lines of hex code only.

Comment: You won't. You'd need to see the source and know what the compilation options were when compiling.

Comment: "a few lines of hex code" is unlikely to be of any use on either board.  You could attempt to disassemble it and see what it might imply as instructions for either system, but it is probably an incomplete fragment.

Comment: @Majenko Oh okay.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It gives error `objdump -d chall.ino.hex :
objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!`

Comment: Disassembling raw files is a pain, you have to specify the architecture as a distinct command line option (and you need to use an avr or arm objdump, not the one for the host system!), may need to tell it about or translate the input format, etc.   And as I said before, if you only have a few lines it's unlikely to yield anything interesting.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I got around 400 lines after disassembling it ! . I don't know what to do now. Can I convert it into C program ?

Comment: No. Now you need to learn assembly language. Welcome to the world of real embedded system programming.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? You have some binary, you don't know what device it's for or what it does. Why are you interested in it? What are you REALLY trying to do?